# Regular expression search, exclude a word

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I like to search for a words containing string `age` in Visual Studio Find, I like to find `age` in `CCAge` or in any other string (like `sage`, `mage`, `abcAGExyz`) but not in `message`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programatically? If so, what language are you using, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This search regex should do the trick: `~(mess)age`

`~(X)` is a [Prevent match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on `X`.

To ignore `Tabpages` as well, you can use `~(mess|tabp)age`. Basically `|` is used as OR, like prevent match on `mess` OR `tabp`, you can add additional words via `|`.

Comment: Hi Petr, your answer is correct. Thank you very much. I am just wondering if I can exclude TabPages as well at same time? Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, you can use `~(mess|tabp)age` for that, see updated answer.

Comment: how it would be if the ignored part needs to be in the end ,like  searching for `ham` find `hammer`, `hamburger` etc.. , but not `hamak`